# How to get a value from a servlet to jsf-page (xhtml)

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, xhtml

I have in a servlet a property, I'm setting it's value in the servlet (with getters and setters). 
Now, when I want to display the value on the jsf-page (xhtml), it has always the value 0. It's like it looses it'a state.

Servlet:

```
private int listSize;       

private Method SomeMethod(some param){
...some code...
setListSize(int size);
...some code...
}

public int getListSize() {
    return listSize;
}

public void setListSize(int size) {
    this.listSize = size;
}
```

xhtml:

```
<h:outputText value="#{someServlet.listSize}" />
```

Comment: http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use servlet, you can put this value to HttpSession and in xhtml, you call:

```
<h:outputText value="#{session.getAttribute(yourAttribute)}"/>
```

Or you use controller, you write:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class yourClassName
```

and in xhtml you call:

```
<h:outputText value="#{yourClassName.yourVariable}"/>
```